# How do I hook up the Angular Material Sidenav with the Content area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have the following (Jade not HTML but I can port if needed):

```
md-sidenav.md-sidenav-left(md-is-locked-open="ctrl.sidebarOpen()", md-is-open="ctrl.sidebarOpen()")
  md-toolbar
    .fa.fa-chevron-right(ng-click="close()", x-type-id="load-search")
  md-list
    md-list-item(ng-repeat="section in ctrl.sections", ng-click="ctrl.dashboardClicked(section.name)", x-type-id="{{section.id}}")
      span {{section.value}}
md-content.body#scroll-area(flex, layout-padding, layout="column")
  df-section-1
  df-section-2
  df-section-3
```

This seems to give me the sort of formatting I am looking for, however, I am not sure how to match the scroll position of the content to the focus on the side-nav.

For example, if all of the sections were one page, I would want the first side-nav list item to be highlighted (focused). When we are on the second page the second, etc.

**Update**

Because it was mentioned in another post, this is inside a directive so I can assign values to the scope or controller.

How would I do this?